# How to remove unused <b></b> tags on my Wordpress site?

Tags: javascript, php, html, css, wordpress

I have the following site: https://www.daenischer-kerzenshop.de/
If i look at the source code via the browser, I can detect empty  tags.

Does anyone happen to know why they are generated and how I can remove them?
I have searched all possible files and removed all code that could possibly cause this.Unfortunately I could not find a usable plugin either.

Here is an example (Browser-> View source code-> line: 1465 ):

```html
<div class="container section-title-container">
  <h1 class="section-title section-title-center">
    <b></b>
    <span class="section-title-main">Qualitätsmerkmale der Dänischen Kerzen</span>
    <b></b>
  </h1>
</div>
```

The site uses the theme Flatsome.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You'll need to search who's placing those empty tags. Removing them after render isn't really useful. Try searching for the source.

Comment: you could try this javascript code

it will get all `b` tags, and filter those who have no children and also it will remove them from the DOM

```javascript
[...document.querySelectorAll('b')].filter((b)=>{ return b.childNodes.length == 0}).forEach((b)=>{b.remove();});
```

add this javascript to each page at the end with a custom html code block

Comment: To remove explicitly just write this code at the end of footer : `$(document).ready(()=>{ $('.section-title.section-title-center').find('b').remove(); });` Make sure your wordpress has JQuery.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Using str_replace() Method

This is the simplest and the easiest method to exclude any unused tags or text. Just add the below code and see the magic.

```
$foo = '
<div class="container section-title-container">
  <h1 class="section-title section-title-center">
    <b></b>
    <span class="section-title-main">Qualitätsmerkmale der Dänischen Kerzen</span>
    <b></b>
  </h1>
</div>';

$bar = str_replace('<b></b>', '', $foo); // Magic mathod
echo $bar;
```

#### The Code After Cleaning Unused Tags

```
<div class="container section-title-container">
  <h1 class="section-title section-title-center">  
    <span class="section-title-main">Qualitätsmerkmale der Dänischen Kerzen</span>   
  </h1>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

the "b" tag created by your Theme developer. it has some styles in your theme.
he/she styled the "section-title b" tag for making the title centered. either it is not a standard way to make a title text centered. you can try this way:

put this code into your css file and see the result with clearing your cache by ctrl + F5:

```
.section-title b {
  display: none;
}
.section-title.section-title-center {
  justify-content: center;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Those  tags actually are being used by the theme author for styling purposes, so  you can't remove or hide them without modifiyng the look of the page. Notice that they have the following styles assigned:

```
.section-title b {
    display: block;
    -webkit-box-flex: 1;
    -ms-flex: 1;
    flex: 1;
    height: 2px;
    opacity: .1;
    background-color: currentColor;
}
```

They represent the thin lines at both sides of the titles.

So, even they are empty, they represent a visual element in your page style.

Answer (score -2):

If you still have Gutenberg editor this works.
**Click all pages - > find your page and click Gutenberg editor -> top-right side click three dots -> Code Editor**.

Comment: Thank you. Unfortunately this theme doesn't use a gutenberg editor. The empty tags are not present in the used code editor, but then the empty bold tags appear in the source code.

Comment: That looks like it is the design of the element. Look with inspect element in chrome where typo says  "QUALITÄTSMERKMALE DER DÄNISCHEN KERZEN ". Don't know if this is helpful.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).